# Converting "Degrees Decimal Minutes" to "Decimal degrees" in Python

Tags: python, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to convert the following format to decimal degrees: 45° 17,896' N

Is there any module that I can use? I tried using dms2dec:

```
from dms2dec.dms_convert import dms2dec
lat = dms2dec("45° 17,896' N")
print(lat)
```

The output is not correct (position is somewhat wrong), so I assume that dms2dec does not support "Degrees Decimal Minutes" format. Any advice?

Comment: You try to convert DM to decimal degrees whereas the lib is for DMS. It can't work

Comment: @ThomasG77 is there a lib for DM?

Comment: No but the "lib" is the answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dirty implementation for Degrees Decimal Degree based on this DMS implementation into the wild e.g https://gist.github.com/chrisjsimpson/076a82b51e8540a117e8aa5e793d06ec (verified the result was coherent using online https://www.pgc.umn.edu/apps/convert/)

```py
import re

def ddm2dec(dms_str):
    """Return decimal representation of DDM (degree decimal minutes)
    
    >>> ddm2dec("45° 17,896' N")
    48.8866111111F
    """
    
    dms_str = re.sub(r'\s', '', dms_str)
    
    sign = -1 if re.search('[swSW]', dms_str) else 1
    
    numbers = [*filter(len, re.split('\D+', dms_str, maxsplit=4))]

    degree = numbers[0]
    minute_decimal = numbers[1] 
    decimal_val = numbers[2] if len(numbers) > 2 else '0' 
    minute_decimal += "." + decimal_val

    return sign * (int(degree) + float(minute_decimal) / 60)

print(ddm2dec("45° 17,896' N"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I also tested and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/medo-mi/dms-to-dd/blob/main/dms_dd.py

```
import re

#Degrees Minutes Seconds to Decimal Degrees
def dms_dd(dd):
    dd = f"""{dd}"""
    dd = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9. ]', '', dd)
    dd = dd.split(" ")
    return round(float(dd[0])+(float(dd[1])/60)+(float(dd[2])/3600), 8)
```